# iPhone 64bit Alter Table doesn't work

Tags: ios, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

When I run my application on 32 bit Simulator everything it's ok, but when I run application on 64 bit I receive an error message and my table in the Database is empty.

```
{
                NSUserDefaults* ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                id test = [ud objectForKey:@"upgraded_Info"];
                if (test==nil) {
                    [self execute:@"ALTER TABLE Info ADD COLUMN enableAddressBookBackup INTEGER"];
                    [self execute:@"ALTER TABLE Info ADD COLUMN lastBackup TEXT"];
                    [self execute:@"ALTER TABLE Info ADD COLUMN addressBookBackupInterval INTEGER"];
                    NSArray* statuses = [[self findObjectsOfClass:[Info class]] all];
                    for (Statusobj* so in statuses) {
                        so.enableABookBackup = 0;
                        so.aBookBackupInterval = 10;
                        [self saveObject:];
                    }
                    [ud setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"upgraded_StatusInfo"];
                    [ud synchronize];
                }
            }
```

In both situations I receive this warning, but when I run on 64 no result in DB:

```
"WARNING: preparing (without result) failed for query 'ALTER TABLE Info ADD COLUMN enableAddressBookBackup INTEGER'"
```

It is something special that I need to change?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: In both situation I receive this warning, but when I run on 64 no result in  DB:"WARNING: preparing (without result) failed for query 'ALTER TABLE StatusInfo ADD COLUMN enableAddressBookBackup INTEGER'"